# Fail to show an image using php and html

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to show an image from a database using php and html but I've got a problem with my code. There is no problem with the connection with the sql database. The problem is in the tag img src. Is it the right way to put the image from the database ?
Here is the code :

```
 <?php 
$rowid = $_GET['id'];
$conn= @mysqli_connect($_SESSION['servername'],$_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['database']) or die(mysql_error());
$verifExistence1 = "SELECT * FROM `annonces` WHERE id='$rowid';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $verifExistence1);
while($row =  @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $pic1=$row['pic1'];
    echo "<div id=\"slideShowImages\">
        <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $pic1 ); ?>\"  alt=\"Slide 1\"/>";
```

Comment: Well, you suppress your errors with `@` in front, so we don't really know if it connected or not. You should enable error-reporting [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), and remove the suppression. But passing the connection details in sessions...? Never seen that before.

Comment: There is no problem with the connection with the sql database. The problem is in the tag img src. Is it the right way to put the image from the database ?

Comment: You're already inside PHP and using `<?php echo base64_encode...?>`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about it - *I smell an answer from this...*

Comment: `or die(mysql_error());` also wrong API.

Comment: The problem didn't come from the connection with sql database. The problem is from this line                                                             src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $pic1 ); ?>\"

Comment: you need to learn how to debug and you've been told twice to use error reporting and also told that you are already inside PHP with the `base64_encode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have php tags inside php tags, so the echo should be:

```
echo "<div id=\"slideShowImages\">
<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
 . base64_encode( $pic1 ) . "\"  alt=\"Slide 1\"/>";
```

I also think that you forgot to close the div?

Comment: Cool @IsmailLaabdi :)